# How to install the Brunel package in a R notebook on Spark 2.0

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-science-experience, dsx

I am trying to install the Brunel viz package in a R notebook on #DSX on SPARK 2.0 cluster. It should be possible to install this pacakge however I dont know how. Any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install brunel library in R notebook, i followed following instructions from brunel github page which seems to be working:-

`install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("Brunel-Visualization/Brunel", subdir="R")`

Use `library(brunel)` to use it.

Reference:- https://github.com/Brunel-Visualization/Brunel/tree/master/R

Thanks,
Charles.